# Memberidrequiredexception for kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Passed group.id and seen no problem with kafka version 3.2. But when updated to kafka 3.4 getting info called Memberidrequiredexception the group member needs to have a valid id before actually entering a consumer group. On next attemp its successful joined group.

getting info called Memberidrequiredexception the group member needs to have a valid id before actually entering a consumer group. How to overcome this

Comment: did u solve @srinivas ?